# how to publish an infopath form with code behind on to the sharpeoint server? (Sharepoitn 2007)

Tags: infopath

hey guyz i am having an issue with the infopath forms in sharepoint. can anybody help me how to deploy an infopath form with code behind it on to the sharepoint server. I dont have the access to the server as an administrator. can anybody tell me how many ways can i publish the infopath form so that i can view it on a browser and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article covering this. Try googling next time.

http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/deploy-an-infopath-2007-form-with-managed-code-to-a-browser-enabled-sharepoint-document-library/

You'll need someone with administrative privileges to publish the form to end users.